# Ok on virtual box is gray

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I cannot resolve the problem "The hardware virtualization is enabled in the Acceleration section of the system page although it is not supported by the host system. It should be disabled in order to start the virtual system" But when I try turn it off I cant press Ok when no other problems I am aware of are detected.

Comment: Is virtualization enabled in the bios?, usually not by default on most PC's

Comment: I agree with the above. I always have to turn Virtualization on in BIOS first before trying it in the virtualizing app